# Excel VBA 'dim as Variant' won't allow 'for each' looping

Tags: excel, vba, charts, foreach

I'm in a bit of a trap with my code. I'm trying to delete charts that occupy the same merged cell, but I'm getting an error. The code wont compile `for each ScrapChart in AllChartsInBox()` if scrapchart isn't set as variant, but then I get Run-time error 91 trying to run `ScrapChart.delete`.

Why Does Scrapchart have to be set as variant, but SheetChart works fine in the `For Each SheetChart In Ws_Charts.ChartObjects` loop when it's been set as a ChartObject?

```
option explicit
Dim NumberofChartsinRange, ChartBoxIndex As Long
Dim SheetChart, AllChartsInBox() As ChartObject
Dim ScrapChart As Variant

Set Chartbox = Ws_Charts.Range("A1:F6")
Ws_Charts.Cells(1,1).Formula2 = formulastring

Chartbox.Merge
Chartbox.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
Chartbox.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom

NumberofChartsinRange = 0

If Ws_Charts.ChartObjects.Count = 0 Then

Else

    ReDim AllChartsInBox(Ws_Charts.ChartObjects.Count - 1)
    
    For Each SheetChart In Ws_Charts.ChartObjects
        If Not Intersect(SheetChart.TopLeftCell, Chartbox) Is Nothing Then
            NumberofChartsinRange = NumberofChartsinRange + 1
            Set AllChartsInBox(ChartBoxIndex) = SheetChart: ChartBoxIndex = ChartBoxIndex + 1
        End If
    Next
End If

If NumberofChartsinRange > 1 Then
    For Each ScrapChart In AllChartsInBox
        ScrapChart.Delete
    Next ScrapChart
End If
```

Comment: Normally one does not use a `For Each` loop on an array. More importantly, elements of your array may be `Nothing` since it has the same number of elements as `Ws_Charts.ChartObjects`, but you are probably not adding all chartobjects to the array.

Comment: Also important: you need to repeat the variable type otherwise it's `Variant`: `Dim NumberofChartsinRange As Long, ChartBoxIndex As Long` and so on.

Comment: You are iterating an array - use a `For...Next` loop.

Comment: Might be easier to use a Collection instead of an array - no need to worry about resizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single pass through the ChartObjects collection:

```vb
Dim SheetChart, co As ChartObject, ChartBox As Range
Dim tmp As ChartObject, foundOne As Boolean, i As Long

Set ChartBox = Ws_charts.Range("A1:F6")
Ws_charts.Cells(1, 1).Formula2 = formulastring

ChartBox.Merge
ChartBox.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
ChartBox.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom

For i = Ws_charts.ChartObjects.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set co = Ws_charts.ChartObjects(i)
    If Not Intersect(co.TopLeftCell, ChartBox) Is Nothing Then
        If Not foundOne Then 'first chart found?
            Set tmp = co
            foundOne = True
        Else
            'multiple charts - delete the first one and this one...
            If Not tmp Is Nothing Then tmp.Delete
            co.Delete
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Except for needing an extra `End If` at the end, this works.

Comment: Where was the missing `End If` ?

Comment: You need 3 'End If' statements at the end, you opened 3 'If' statements during the `For...Next` loop.

Comment: `If Not tmp Is Nothing Then tmp.Delete` is a single-line `If` and doesn't require a closing `End If`...

Comment: You are correct, I'd not realised that tmp.delete and co.delete weren't in the same `If`, and I forgot about single line `If`s